# Visual Studio Code Fails to find WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to compile some C code in visual studio with gcc using WSL.

I've got a super simple configuration that executes on an F5 Press

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Build And Run",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/BuildAndRun.bat",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "externalConsole": true,
        "environment": [],

    },]
```

Which then should execute the batch file that contains a simple call to wsl and gcc

```
@echo off
wsl gcc main.c
pause
```

When I run this bat file by clicking on it, it works and everything compiles. however when I press F5 I get an error that *'wsl' is not recognized as an internal or external command*. 
I've tried adding it to Path and that didnt help.
I should also add that when I run the command inside the vs terminal it works, which just confuses me even more.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

> #### program (required)
>
> Specifies the full path to the executable the debugger will launch or attach to.
>
> The debugger requires this location in order to load debug symbols

`program` is the executable for debugger to attach, not compile your code. Compile your C program via `preLaunchTask` in `launch.json` and config that command in `tasks.json`. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw for reference.

Also, you may need WSL-Remote plugin and work directly in WSL, See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl